# Does the memory of an object with no reference get cleared automatically?

Tags: c++, oop, arduino

I know, this is a stupid question, but I have a few classes that extend another class, and I have a variable (`Test* currentTest`) in which I have one instance of one of the classes is saved. It always changes what is in the variable, and after a few changes, the entire program just crashes (either restarting or just freezing) and I wonder if the memory actually gets cleared automatically or if I'm just stupid.

EDIT: Here's a sketch for testing. It works fine for a few seconds, but then crashes (Probably because RAM is full). This is *basically* what my program is doing, just with way more classes and update functions that actually do something.

```
class Test {
  public:
    virtual void update();
};
void Test::update() {}

class TestA : public Test {
  public:
    virtual void update();
  private:
    int a = 0;
    int abc[50]; // allocate a lot of memory, just like in the actual program
};

class TestB : public Test {
  public:
    virtual void update();
  private:
    int a = 0;
    int abc[20]; // allocate a lot of memory, just like in the actual program
};

Test* currentTest;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  currentTest = new TestA();
  Serial.println("Start!");
}

void loop() {
  currentTest->update();
  delay(100);
}

void TestA::update() {
  Serial.println("Running A");
  a++;
  if(a >= 5) {
    currentTest = new TestB();
  }
}

void TestB::update() {
  Serial.println("Running B");
  a++;
  if(a >= 5) {
    currentTest = new TestA();
  }
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have gagbage collection, if a value of a variable is changing without reason I'm suspecting undefined behavior. Please post your code.

Comment: the crash origin maybe is segmentation fault. check it out and please explain your problem by details and code

Comment: My code has more than 2500 lines, and the variables content is _supposed_ to change. The problem is that, after doing it like 3 times, it crashes, and my guess is that it is because of memory corruption.

Comment: The key information we are missing is: How is Test *currentTest allocated? Is it allocated with a call to malloc/new? Is it returned from a function call? Is it pointing to a declared Test object within the crashing function?  Best guess is that currentTest is being deleted or deallocated, and then referenced/changed by one of your classes.

Comment: do I get it right that `Test* currentTest` points to an instance of class derived from `Test`? There are many things that can go wrong, the polymorphic class should be designed properly and instance should be still alive. Is it allocated in heap?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#:~:text=Lifetime%20of%20an%20object%20is,it%20were%20a%20scalar%20object. might help

Comment: Can you post a cut-down version of your code that exhibits the same problem?

Comment: @random_username With a program that crashes, and you don't know where to start, it's very hard for us to help you. My advice would be to take it to your professor and get some guidance on debugging. You can also have a go at that yourself first, make sure you're setup with a debugger, perhaps read some tutorials and advice surrounding that debugger. This is also some great [general debugging advice](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: "it is too much code to consider it all" is like surrender in front of the error. Isolating the problem is the only way to fix it. If you remove everything that is not related to the problem is it still 2500 lines? The issue is often in 1 or 2 lines of code, to fix them you need to find them. Read about [mcve]. Starting from your whole project and removing stuff until you have a small understandable example is a viable way to understand and fix such error. And if you don't find it, you'll have a small example to post here

Comment: indeed you have lots of  leaks and probably run out of memory at some point. I dont know arduino, does it have smart pointers ?

Comment: This is a good question that many people don't think of.

Comment: By the way, the Arduino (all of them, I think?) has extremely limited memory, something like 32 kilobytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaking memory until you run out of memory. Every `new` should have a `delete`. If we look only at the `update` method and ignore all the rest, you should `delete` the old `currentTest` before you assign a new one:

```
void TestA::update() {
  Serial.println("Running A");
  a++;
  if(a >= 5) {
    delete currentTest;
    currentTest = new TestB();
  }
}
```

However, we cannot ignore all the rest! `currentTest` is a pointer to the current object and you cannot call the destructor from within a member function without running into problems. The `Test` objects should not be responsible for deleting themself. You should have something else that manages the `Test`s. Actually you should use smart pointers, though without you could use something like this:

```
struct TestManager {
     Test * test = nullptr;
     int counter = 0;
     void update() {
          if (test) {
              test->update();
              ++counter;
          }
          if (test && counter == 5) {
              delete test;
              test = new TestA;
          }
     }
 };
```

However, instead of manually managing the raw pointer you really should use smart pointers. In the above I always create a `TestA`, while you want to create instances of different subclasses, thats probably a matter for a different question.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No. may be you need std::shared_ptr<>